# I understand that the pattern is increasing and decreasing but I'm not sure how to make an equation that states that.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find a formula for the general term $a_n$ of the sequence (starting with $a_1$):
$\{3,7,3,7,...\}$

Comment: you have $a_{2n-1} = 3$ and $a_{2n} = 7?$

Answer (score 3):

$a_n=|3\sin(n\frac{\pi}{2})|+|7\cos(n\frac{\pi}{2})|$

Answer (score 2):

or you can write:
$$
a_n = 5 + 2(-1)^n
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
  a_n = 7 - 4\bigg\lceil\Big(\frac{n}{2} - \Big\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\Big\rfloor\Big)\bigg\rceil
$$

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat vaguely stated. (What does the word *formula* in "Find a formula" exactly mean?)

You might consider
$$a_n = \begin{cases} 3,&\text{if $n$ is odd}\\7,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
a formula.